# Marginal contribution of each observation to posterior moments and (differential) entropy are decreasing in the number of observations?

Tags: bayesian, posterior, entropy

In the Beta-Binomial and Gaussian settings, indeed, the marginal contribution of each observation to the posterior moments (I could check first and second) and (differential) entropy are decreasing in the number of observations.

Is that result more general? Is there a proof for it?

ETA: Xi'an commented that the result generalizes to all exponential families, under conjugate priors (I presume it refers to both entropy and moments). However, I need a proof for those claims (I'm incapable of proving them)

Comment: The result directly generalises to all exponential families, under conjugate priors.

Comment: @Xi'an Do you have a reference that provides a proof for those results so I can educate myself? Even if it's an immediate result, I'm not able to provide a proof for it.

Comment: As it is put right now, your question looks more like a tautology. Please elaborate and add relevant equations, formulae etc. Differential entropy is the $E[-\log(f(x))]$ where $f$ is a PDF. Naturally, when looking at the mean (or its estimate, the average) - the marginal contribution of each observation (=its effect on the result) decreases in the number of samples, as the whole sum is divided by $N$.